# NetLogo: n-of error when all turtles die

Tags: netlogo, die

I have a simulation where turtles walk onto red patches and die, which works, but everything that has `n-of` in it reports an error as soon as most of/all turtles are dead. I do understand the error, since the simulation tries to get `n-of` while there is no turtle left, but how do i fix that? Is there a way to use n-of when at the end of the simulation all the turtles are dead?
If there is, how do I do it?,
and if not, is there an alternative way to making the turtles die on red patches?
My simulation needs every turtle to be gone as soon as it walks on a red patch, but they can't walk on/over each other, which would make it hard to let them gather on one red patch (there are about 500 turtles).

Thank you!
edit:
I edited my code so that I don't need n-of anymore. Now, the part of my code where I want one turtle to set pen-mode to "down" is

`to go
....
ask one-of turtles [set pen-mode "down"]
....
end`

and the error message is now:

> ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.
>   error while observer running ASK
>   called by procedure GO
>   called by Button 'go'

as soon as the simulation ends.

The `one-of turtles` was suggested, but for now every turtle sets its pen-mode to "down", but I only want one turtle to do that.

Comment: You should post your code and the error message that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to use at most `n` turtles. That is, if there at least `n` turtles, you should use `n` of them, otherwise you should just use all the turtles. We can turn this into reporter pretty easily:

```
to-report at-most-n-of [ n agentset ]
  ifelse count agentset > n [
    report n-of n agentset
  ] [
    report agentset
  ]
end
```

You use this exactly like `n-of` but it won't error if there aren't enough turtles.

Answer (score 2):

You are not telling us what you are using `n-of` *for*, so it's hard to suggest an alternative approach. But in general the way to prevent `n-of` from crashing when there are not enough turtles to select, is to use something like:

```
n-of (min list n count turtles) turtles
```

where `n` is the number of turtles that you would like to select if possible.

Comment: I have about 500 brown patches, and every patch can spawn 1 turtle. When I tell 200 patches to spawn one turtle (with a slider), I have 200 turtles, how do I tell your code how many turtles I have? Do I just fill the name of the slider in where the "n" is, even though the slider refers to patches, not to turtles? Or am I completely wrong here? :-D

Comment: In the code above, `count turtles` is how many turtles you _currently_ have. `n` is how many turtles you would like to select out of those you currently have. But I don't understand your question because I don't understand what you are trying to do. You're not wrong; just unclear. What are you trying to select? What do you want to select it for? Edit your question. Post a bit of code... at least show us the line where you're trying to use `n-of`...

Comment: I changed the code now, but the error is about the same. I want, for example, to have one turtle pen down. 
"ask turtle random 1 [set pen-mode "down"]"
but as soon as that random turtle dies, I get an error. Do I fix that with your suggestion?

Comment: Never try to randomly select a turtle by its `who` number (which is what `turtle random 1` would do - except that `random 1` is always equal to `0`). If you want to select one random turtle, use `one-of turtles`. But we still can't help you more than that until you **edit your question and post the code for what you are trying to do**.