# How to randomly select two patches from neighbors4 in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to select 2 neighbors randomly, like we have the facility to select 8 neighbors from "neighbors" command similarly to select 4 neighbors we use `neighbors4` command but what if we want to select only 2 neighbors randomly from the 8 neighbors.

I want to do something like this:

```
ask n-of 2 patches from neighbors with [pcolor = white]
  [set pcolor blue]
```

but, as there is no `from` command so I don't know how it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close! What you want is:

```
n-of 2 neighbors with [pcolor = white]
```

But what if there are possibly less than two neighbors that are white? In that case, I'd suggest using the [`at-most-n-of` reporter defined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26961252/487946).

Answer (score 3):

You have basically solved this yourself:

`neighbors` (or in your case `neighbors with [condition]`) returns the agentset that `n-of` expects, so all you need is

```
[
 ask n-of 2 neighbors with [pcolor = white] [ set pcolor blue ]
]
```

.